# For send to Printer with ShellExecute

Tags: c++, winapi

```
ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", (Url + url3).c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

With this code, I open the url I want. But I want it to send the pdf displayed in the opened url directly to the printer that I will specify. thank you for your answers.

Comment: What about trying the command `"print"` instead of `"open"`?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not send to the printer. I want it to be sent to the printer that I will specify without opening the preview.

Comment: What about the "printto" verb?

Comment: Unfortunately "printto"

Comment: The pdf page opens with the code I gave. When I press print from this page, I can select a printer and print. What I want is to print directly without any action. we can say that the page opened in the browser is written directly.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your comments. We do not send directly to the printer with ctrl+p. We open the print screen. It's not like sending it directly to the printer.